# Can someone explain what's a "Clearing Event"?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, analysis

I'm working with a friend where he's trying to simulate a clearing event for 10uF capacitor. As of now, he's using a 10uF capacitor, a power supply running 48 volts, and a 40kohm 50Watt resistor. He believes that if there is a contaminate in the structure of the capacitor.  As voltage is increased the contaminate will burn away creating a temporary short and leaving the capacitor with a slightly less capacitance value. So, he wants to simulate that by adding a DC contactor into the circuit along with a switch and a resistor. I'm having issues with grasping what a clearing event is, I'm wondering if there's another name for it. Also, if he's adding a resistor for the switch in order to create the short, my guess is that the value would need to be pretty high in order to handle the high voltage. I'll attach the spec sheet for the contactor that we're using. The highlighted values are what we're using. It's a GIGAVAC GV240 contactor, the capacitor is KEMET C44PUGR5100RASK

[image]

I'll also attach a simulation he created on LTspice here:
[image]

Comment: What kind of capacitor, can you show some of the circuits? There is a tool if you edit the question and click on the circuit tool button.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: No need to be sorry, thanks for fixing

Comment: What does the manufacturer say about these events?

Comment: There isn't much to go off of when it comes to the manufacturer's website unfortunately. I sent them a message and am still waiting for a response.

Comment: Sounds like a metalized film capacitor that ‘self heals’. If there is a localized failure of the dielectric, the resultant arc heals the fault. These are commonly X2 class capacitors specified for connection across the mains.